# Undefined symbols for std::basic_string when linking c++ using gfortran?

Tags: c++, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to link a C++ file with my Fortran 90 program, but I'm running into a link error when using gfortran.

My Fortran files are compiled with:
`gfortran -c -o obj/file.o file.f90 -O0 -g3 -ffree-line-length-none -fcheck-array-temporaries -fbounds-check` and my C++ file is compiled using `g++-4.7 -c -o obj/cppfile.o cppfile.cpp -O0 -g3 -std=c++11`

Then, all are linked together with gfortran:
`gfortran -o program obj/file.o obj/cppfile.o -O0 -g3 -ffree-line-length-none -fcheck-array-temporaries -fbounds-check -lm -llapack -lc -lgfortran -lgcc -lstdc++`

When doing this, I get the following link errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "std::basic_string, std::allocator::basic_string(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&&)", referenced from:
>
> > std::basic_string, std::allocator > std::operator+, std::allocator >(char const*, std::basic_string, std::allocator >&&) in cppfile.o
> >     std::basic_string, std::allocator > std::operator+, std::allocator >(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&&, char const*) in cppfile.o
> >     std::basic_string, std::allocator > std::operator+, std::allocator >(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >&&) in cppfile.o
> >     std::basic_string, std::allocator > std::operator+, std::allocator >(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) in cppfile.o
> >     component::component(component&&) in cppfile.o "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::operator=(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&&)", referenced from:
> >     *function* in cppfile.o
> >     component::operator=(component&&) in cppfile.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [program] Error 1

My c++ file looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct component
{
    string num;     // numerator of component
    string den;     // denominator of component
    int ind;        // index of variable
};

extern "C"{
void subroutine_ (int num, const int* array)
{
    ...
    return;
}
```

Any thoughts as to why this would be happening? I made sure to link the -lstdc++ library. Could it have something to do with my use of the C++11 standard, related to the string library?

Comment: What happens if you instead try to link with: `g++ -std=c++11 -o program obj/file.o obj/cppfile.o -O0 -g3 -lm -llapack -lgfortran`

Comment: @NikosC.: That's the most likely answer.

Comment: Doing that, it links without error, but running the program immediately fails with `redmech(25962) malloc: *** mmap(size=18446744073587937280) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Memory allocation failed`

Comment: I should mention, the Fortran code holds the main program, i.e., PROGRAM. Also, it compiles and runs without error using gfortran to link without the c++ subroutine. Also, in my last comment, `redmech` is the actual name of the program.

Comment: Alright, after doing a little testing, when linking with `gfortran` the problem appears to be a combination of the `-std=c++11` and either a string vector or vector of my struct `component`. In a simpler code, if I remove `-std=c++11`, I can have vectors of either type without problem.

Comment: Just a side note. The name of your C++ functions suggests that it is to be called from the Fortran code. Fortran uses pass-by-address calling convention and hence the dummy arguments of the C++ function should be pointers. The value of `size` in `mmap` is `0xFFFFFFFFF8C05000` which looks suspiciously similar to sign-extended `0xF8C05000`, which could be 32-bit truncation of a pointer to a stack address on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution appears to be to remove the `-std=c++11` from the compilation of the C++ code. With it, combining linking C++ code with a vector of strings (or structs that contain a string) causes the above errors.

I'm going to file a bug in the GCC Bugzilla on this, and use my solution as a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: It turns out I was (unintentionally) linking the wrong libstdc++. The gcc I'm using is 4.7.2, installed via homebrew alongside the Apple-supplied gcc. Gfortran was linking to that libstdc++, when I link using `gfortran -o program file.o cppfile.o /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.2/gcc/lib/libstdc++.a` there is no error.